# How Do I prevent leading underscores for variable names when using Proc Transpose

Tags: sas, transpose, proc

I am attempting to transform a dataset that looks like:

```
  A        B        C
2011      NH        25
2011      MA        40 
2015      CA        50
2016      KY        58
```

I want the output to be:

```
 B     2011     2015      2016
NH      25        -         -
MA      40        -         -
CA       -        50        -
KY       -        -         58
```

Currently my code is:

```
 proc transpose data = Test out = Test2(drop = _label_);
     id Year_Enter;
     Var Numeric;
     by Category NOTSORTED;
 run;
```

However, when I run this all of my column names have an underscore in front such as _2011  , _2015 , _2016.

How do I prevent the underscore from being added?

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you want a variable name that does not follow SAS's rules for variable names?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a dataset then you can should use valid names for the variables. Variable names cannot normally start with digits.  You can use the PREFIX= option on the PROC TRANSPOSE statement to pick what characters you prefix the values of your numeric variable with to generate valid names.  So you might use `PREFIX=Y` to generate variables names like `Y2011` or use `PREFIX=Year_` to generate names like `Year_2011`.  You can use the `IDLABEL` statement to put the bare numeric string as the LABEL of the variable.

```
proc transpose data=have prefix=Year_ out=want(drop=_name_);
  by State;
  id Year;
  idlabel Year;
  var Value;
  format year 4.;
run;

proc print;
run;
```

[image]

```
proc print label;
run;
```

[image]

But it really looks like you want to produce a REPORT and not a DATASET. For example you could create that report using PROC REPORT from your original dataset without need for PROC TRANSPOSE.

```
proc report missing data=have ;
  column state value,year ;
  define state / group ;
  define year / across ' ';
  define value / sum ' ';
run;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to have extended variable names enabled. SAS variables must follow certain [naming conventions](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=lrcon&docsetTarget=p18cdcs4v5wd2dn1q0x296d3qek6.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en#p0w2dq3equv4b3n1m81ydfv0j7v0), some of which can be overridden:

> - The name can be up to 32 bytes in length.
> - The name can contain letters of the Latin alphabet, numerals, or underscores.
> - The name cannot contain blanks or special characters except for the underscore.
> - **The name must begin with a letter of the Latin alphabet (A–Z, a–z) or the underscore.**

If you enable the option `options validvarname=any;`, you will remove the underscore in front of numeric variable names and use extended SAS naming rules. See the example below.

```
data have;
    input A B$ C;
    datalines;
2011 NH 25
2011 MA 40
2015 CA 50
2016 KY 58
;
run;

options validvarname=any;
proc transpose data = have out = want(drop = _label_);
     id A;
     Var C;
     by B NOTSORTED;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Transposition into a form such that data values (year) become metadata (year as column name) is commonly indicative of a reporting transformation.  Consider using `Proc TABULATE` to render the transformation.

```
data have; input
A        B $       C; datalines;
2011      NH        25
2011      MA        40 
2015      CA        50
2016      KY        58
run;

proc tabulate data=have;
  class a;
  class b / order=data;
  var c;
  table b='',a=''*c=''*sum='';
run;
```

[image]